# Validate that a xml file is a file with javascript before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Let's say I have an xml file I want to upload through a html form using php but I want to verify first that the xml file is an actual file using javascript. I have a form with only one input and this piece of javascript code:

```
function Validate(form) {
var _validFileExtensions = [".xml"];

var arrInputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
    var oInput = arrInputs[i];
    if (oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
        if (sFileName.length > 0) {
            var blnValid = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                    blnValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!blnValid) {
                alert(oInput.type);
                //alert("Lo siento, " + sFileName + " es invalido, la única extensión permitida es: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        alert(oInput.type);
        //alert("Tienes que seleccionar un archivo");
        return false;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

I'm just putting this piece to describe the problem, which is that file.xml isn't a file, is empty, if I try to submit any type of file that I can find on my computer, like "javascript.js", "newdocument.txt" or any kind of file, javascript "file.type" does match "file", but if I submit a "file.xml" it alerts "submit",  same thing if I click submit without selecting any file. Which leads me to believe that .xml files are treated as some kind of instruction or something.

I know I also have to validate server side and stuff, but for now I want to validate client side using javascript, so, is there a way to validate that "file.xml" is a file?

**EDIT: (Added full code and fiddle>**
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
        <title>XML a PDF</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="javita.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
            <form action="transforma.php" method="post"  mimetype="text/xml" enctype="text/xml" onsubmit="return Validate(this);" name="transforma">
            <label for="file">Filename: </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also tried with:

```
<form action="transforma.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Validate(this);" name="transforma">
```

Same result

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkwWq/2/)

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Maybe the `form.getElementsByTagName('input')` selects the wrong input.

Comment: There, I added the html, but as I mentioned, if the file isn't .xml, like a .txt or .dll or any other than .xml, javascript does detect its type as file. While if it is .xml or empty, it alerts "submit".

Comment: First of all, you code has an error in it: a `}` too many. Secondly.. I'm only getting 'undefined' in the alert. http://jsfiddle.net/xkwWq/

Comment: I was just trying to exemplify what I mean, here's the fiddle to the code showing exactly what I mean. If you don't choose a file or choose a xml file, you'll get alerted "submit", if you choose any other file, you'll get alerted "file".

Answer (score 1):

If you have not realized it yet, you're just totally looking in the wrong direction with the assumptions you do.

First of all, javascript does not differ on the contents of a string here. It just operates on a string. Whether that string contains `"I hate you javascript, go home"` or `"this-file-extension-is-better-than-others.txt"` or your so missing `"file.xml"` - it will always work the same here.

See this comment of yours two days ago:

> I'm more interested on knowing is why a xml file isn't recognized as a file by javascript, or how can I accomplish javascript to acknowledge a xml file as a file.

So I let you know: The XML file is recognized as a file by javascript.

After I have introduced that knowledge to you (and I hope you're openhearted accepting this to know, too, as it solves the largest part of your problem), then let's see what's going on here.

First of all you're doing too many things at once. For example, you'd like to get the file input element. As it doesn't have an ID you iterate through all inputs. That's just not necessary. If the problem is that the element can't well be identified, give the form an ID so that you can:

```
form.id || (form.id = "id".concat(+new Date, parseInt(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 16))));

var fileName = document.querySelector("#".concat(form.id, " input[type=file]")).value;
```

Done. There is the string of the fileName. If you then verify this, you can easily see that it always contains the filename. If not yet choosen, it's an empty string, if choosen, it's the "fakepath" string of the filename. At least at this point you have to realize that it always will be a string, regardless of which file you've been chosen.

Next thing is that you should create a function that validates a filename's extension against your whitelist. This has the benefit, that you can just use it on any string no matter where you got it from:

```
var fileExtension = function (file) {
    var extensions = [".xml"];
    var match;
    extensions.every(function (extension) {
        var e = /([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g;
        if (new RegExp(extension.replace(e, "\\$1") + '$', 'i').test(file)) {
            match = extension;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    return match;
}
```

When done this, you can easily validate the form, see this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZj85/

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely foolproof but you could try this:

```
function validate(form) {
    var file = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var ext = file.value.substring(file.value.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (ext == "xml") {
        // Do something when it is an xml file
    } else {
        // Do something else when it is not
    }
    return false
}
```

`.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. You want the first one since that is your file input.
`var ext = ...` gets the extension, or at least what is behind the last `.` (including). But a user can still upload another filetype but just change the extension, so you need some serverside validation as well.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkwWq/1/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, I know this is the work around, but what I'm more interested on knowing is why a xml file isn't recognized as a file by javascript, or how can I accomplish javascript to acknowledge a xml file as a file. I updated your fiddle to exemplify what I'm looking for, if you leave file empty, or choose a .xml file, you'll get alerted "submit", if you choose any other file, you'll get alerted "file". http://jsfiddle.net/xkwWq/2/